# Show only items that return a result

Tags: magento2.3, database

I am displaying data from database but how would i only show items that return a result from $qtyBackordered

```
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Thecoachsmb\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\View\CollectionFactory as ViewCollectionFactory;

class Article extends Template

    /**
     * CollectionFactory
     * @var null|CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_viewCollectionFactory = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ViewCollectionFactory $viewCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ViewCollectionFactory $viewCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_viewCollectionFactory  = $viewCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        /** @var ViewCollection $viewCollection */
        $viewCollection = $this->_viewCollectionFactory ->create();
        $viewCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
        return $viewCollection->getItems();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
public function getCollection()
{
    /** @var ViewCollection $viewCollection */
    $viewCollection = $this->_viewCollectionFactory ->create();
    $viewCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
    if(count($viewCollection->getItems())){
        return $viewCollection->getItems();
    }
    return ''; //return false;
}
```